TYPO3 cache /data/pages huge
I have the following problem. TYPO3 from version 10 clutters up the cache. Immediately after I delete the cache directory, several MB are created again. After a few days it is > 50 GB. How can I prevent this or find out where the problem is coming from?

Which cache directory/files exactly amount to that data? Often it's a misconfigured cHash, so that maybe you allow too many URL parameters that each create a unique cache entry (like ke-search URL parameters). That especially applies to old TYPO3 installations like yours with possibly extensions like ke-search that weren't yet properly configured for this. You can compare the cache files and see in which regard the files differ to see what duplication probably happens.

It is the vendor/cache/data/pages folder. I dont use special Extension. Just one custom extension with url parameters. Is there a possibility to deactivate the cache for cHash? I can't cache my extension because of automatic regenerating content from external sources.

You can list custom URL parameters here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Index.html#confval-excludedparameters

These will then be excluded from creating unique cache variants. However, if your page content shall be cached and depends on the parameters, you'll need to output anything related to these parameters with your own caching (uncached plugin execution, doing its own caching in PHP either with or without TYPO3 Cache API).
